# if I don't use foreignkey, How could I connect relation

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class PubSquare(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(60))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

the `author_id` is relation to class `User`.

```
publist = PubSquare.query.order_by(PubSquare.timestamp.desc()).all()
```

In jinja2,

```
{% for pub in publist %}
{{ pub.author_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I need to display the element in `User`.
How Could I Do This?

I can't use foreignkey Because flask-migrate can't migrate models with foreignkeys.
So I have to design models without foreignkeys.

I wish someone could help me, Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to migrate a table with a foreign key so long as your migration doesn't cause an integrity error.

Comment: @dirm But I can't.If I use migrate, "NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column".  But I can re-create the database with the same models.

Comment: What does your model look like when you try to use a foreign key? Can you also include the model it references?

Comment: @dirn  I have new another question about it, could you see it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487475/flask-migrate-doesnt-work-when-i-add-models-with-foreignkey